# Pass multiple values in IN clause using mybatis annotations

Tags: java, database, oracle, annotations, mybatis

I am trying to pass multiple values in a SELECT QUERY consisting of an IN clause. I would like to execute the following query using mybatis:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_COMPARISON_ROW_DIF WHERE SCAN_ID in  (#{childScanIDs})
```

where the `childScanIDs` variable consists of multiple comma separated values. I am passing these values as a String consisting of all the values separated with a comma. Below is the method being used in the mapper interface.

```
@Select(getDifferencesByScanIDs)
    @Results({
            @Result(property="owner", column="OWNER"),
            @Result(property="comparisonName", column="COMPARISON_NAME"),
            @Result(property="scanID", column="SCAN_ID"),
            @Result(property="localRowID", column="LOCAL_ROWID"),
            @Result(property="remoteRowID", column="REMOTE_ROWID"),
            @Result(property="indexValue", column="INDEX_VALUE"),
            @Result(property="status", column="STATUS"),
            @Result(property="lastUpdateTime", column="LAST_UPDATE_TIME")
    })
    List<Difference> getDifferencesByScanIDs(@Param("childScanIDs") String childScanIDs);
```

I am constructing the string of values this way:

```
String scanIDs = StringUtils.join(cmp.getChildScanIDs(), ",");
```

When executing the function, it is raising this exception.

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

### The error may involve com.rs2.automation.soacomparison.dao.differences.DifferencesMapper.getDifferencesByScanIDs-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Any help would be appreciated. I think the problem is that mybatis is not recognizing the values as separate numbers. Another solution would be to execute the query on each number but I wanted to pass all the values at once. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_COMPARISON_ROW_DIF WHERE SCAN_ID in  (#{childScanIDs})
```

If we imagine a list like `2, 13, 15, 16`, this query will result in:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_COMPARISON_ROW_DIF WHERE SCAN_ID in  ('2,13,15,16')
```

As you can see, the value is treated as `String` and not as list, which is not what you need.

I would pass `cmp.getChildScanIDs()` to mybatis, without transforming it to string, and use mybatis' dynamic sql.

Edit the method as:

```
List<Difference> getDifferencesByScanIDs(@Param("childScanIDs") List<Integer> childScanIDs); // or int[]
```

Edit the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_COMPARISON_ROW_DIF WHERE SCAN_ID in 
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="childScanIDs" open="(" separator="," close=")">
    #{item}
    </foreach>
```

---

What it does:

- <foreach>: starts a foreach loop
- item: the name of the current object inside the loop
- index: the index variable (not really needed in this case)
- collection: the name of the collection (as per your definition in the mapper interface)
- open: string to insert before the first iteration
- close: string to insert after the last iteration
- separator: string to insert between an element and another
- #{item}: prints the current item

Link for reference: [MyBatis Dynamic SQL](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution but it is giving me the error: ### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null parameter.  Most JDBC drivers require that the JdbcType must be specified for all nullable parameters. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111

Comment: @gla315 Try telling mybatis which type item is: Replace `#{item}` with `#{item,jdbcType=INTEGER}` inside the foreach

Comment: Tried that but it is giving me invalid SQL statement. This is the query: @Select({"<script>",
        "SELECT *", 
        "FROM DBA_COMPARISON_ROW_DIF",
        "WHERE SCAN_ID IN", 
          "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='childScanIDs'",
            "open='(' separator=',' close=')'>",
            "#{item, jdbcType=INTEGER}",
          "</foreach>",
        "</script>"})

Comment: This is the way I am passing the list of integers: List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(String st : cmp.getChildScanIDs()){
   Integer intNum = new Integer(st);
   list.add(intNum);
  }
  List<Difference> differences = mapperLocal.getDifferencesByScanIDs(list);

Comment: @gla315 I don't know if something has changed since 2013, but as stated [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012691/mybatis-dynamic-sql-inside-annotation) probably dynamic sql doesn't work with annotations. To solve your issue you need dynamic sql, so if you want to use it you need to support XML-based mappers, which is also better IMO because you separate java and sql logic, making things more clear.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't very clear on the documentation. There are several ways to do this but a straight forward way is to just use OGNL. We evaluate any parameters `#{xx}` or `${xx}` (difference explained in the docs) via OGNL.

So you can for example create

```
public class InList {
    public static String build(final List<?> params) {
        return Joiner.on(",").join(params);
    }
}
```

And use it in your query as

```
WHERE SCAN_ID IN (${@InList@build(childScanIds)})
```

Note: Using `${}` opens up accidental or intentional SQL injection problems but, obviously, that is also dependent on your use case so use it carefully.